# DbValidationError: The FieldName field is required, but i set that field as Allow Nulls in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I used EF Model-First to build my databse on Sql server with mvc4 project. In my controller in ActionResult method I ignored all properties which are nullable(set as Allow Null) I got an **ErrorMessage** by DbEntityValidationException *says*: **The ProfileImgUrl field is required.** Now That is the problem since i set that field as allow null !! So this field(ProfileImgUrl) should be unrequired.
[image: picture of the error]
here is my Controller :

```
 SWMModelContainer db = new SWMModelContainer();
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Registration()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registration(User user)
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var crypt = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
                var encryptPass = crypt.Compute(user.Password);

                var users = db.Users.Create();

                users.Email = user.Email;
                users.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                users.LastName = user.LastName;
                users.Password = encryptPass;
                users.PasswordSalt = crypt.Salt;
                users.Gender = "m";
                users.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                int lastProductId = db.Users.Max(item => item.UrId);
                users.UrId = lastProductId + 10;

                db.Users.Add(users);
                try
                {
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "main");
                    }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                {
                    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                                                    validationError.PropertyName,
                                                    validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
                else 
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Registration data is incorrect! ");
                }


            return View();
        }
```

Comment: have you changed the "allow null property" in the model? Go to the model, look for the column, check its properties. Make sure it is "nullable - true". The model EDMX and the Database must be nullable

Comment: @FabioLuz   Exactly you should add that comment as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the model, look for the column, check its properties. Make sure it is "nullable - true". The property in the EDMX model and the column in the Database must be nullable.